# Xmpp library for Typescript

Tags: typescript, xmpp, typescript-typings, node-xmpp

I need a javascript XMPP library for my project which I am developing with Typescript. The problem with typescript is when you want to import external javascript  libraries, you also need to include type definitions for the external library. That being the case, as I searched, there are currently no type definitions for any of the xmpp libraries out there so I'm not able to use any XMPP library in my project.

How can I fix this problem or is there any way to add xmpp libraries to ur project without defining the types for the library.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a XMPP library in typescript in the very early days of typescript.
You can find the code on Github here:
https://github.com/matrix-xmpp/matrix-js

It is on my TODO list to change the license to MIT. Contributions are welcome.